# No such file or directory - gitlab and jmeter CI

Tags: jmeter, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

Facing a issue "NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY" In script - cd "PATH/OF/JMETER".

Load tests:
stage: test
script:
- cd c:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin
- .\jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l testresults.jtl

Answer (score 0):

It means that JMeter is not installed on the machine where your build is running.

Moreover I would say that `No such file or directory` is rather [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) error message and in Linux filesystem there is no drive `c:\`

So either [install JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install) on the machine where you're running your build or use i.e. [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) which automatically downloads JMeter

Comment: Jmeter is installed on my local machine and I am running this from windows machine gitlab account.

Comment: Main problem here (gitlab-ci.yml file) is cd (change directory) command is not working ( cd "c:/apache-jmeter/bin" Is giving the error 'no such file or directory even the jmeter folder in present in c drive of my local machine) .